# Cakephp use Froala Editor not show anythings

Tags: php, cakephp, text-editor, froala

I use Froala Editor for my project cakephp
I've done every step as in the guidelines, but the results are not as expected
I downloaded it and follow the instructions as here [enter link description here](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-cake)

1. download and put Froala folder in app/Plugin/
2. in boostrap.php i have loaded `CakePlugin::load('Froala');`
3. in controller: i have put line: `public $helpers = array('Froala.Froala');`
4. in view: my code is

> ```
> <div id="froala-editor">
>   <p>froala-editor</p>
> </div>
> <?php $this->Froala->editor('#froala-editor'); ?>
> ```

but Froala editor not appear, Please help me!!!! Thank so much

Answer (score 0):

I think, today Froala have release a solution for Cake php 3 which might help your problem.
https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-cake

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

1. open terminal/command prompt (windows)
2. type `composer require froala/wysiwyg-cake` <kbd>enter</kbd>
3. open bootstrap.php (confic folder)
4. add Plugin::load('Froala'); to the end of page
5. open AppController.php (your project/src/controller/AppController)
6. Declare variable `public $helpers = array('Froala.Froala');`
7. In the view page (template) you add `<?= $this->Froala->editor('#froala-editor'');?>`